# titanium backup - Stuck on seaching application data

Tags: android, backup

I saved a backup with titanium, installed a different rom (clean install) and then now I am ready to restore my backup. The problem is:

When I open Titanium, it's stuck at "Searching Application Data" message and it won't let me do anything.

I already tried:

- uninstall and reinstall Titanium
- tried with a older version
- tried removing SU permission (no message but I can't do anything)
- tried typing in the terminal as suggested on XDA developers the following

> ```
> su
> restorecon -FR /data/media/0
> ```

- with no luck

I don't know what else to try. My backup folder has stuff in it, I just need to be able to launch the app...

Any idea? Sorry I can't be more precise but I don't really know any more details than that, apart that I am on android 7.1.1.

thanks

Comment: I do Face the same issue. I think this app is incompatible with latest nightly as it was working seamlessly.

Comment: Adding the storage permission in the settings did it for me.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help]. See what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](/help/dont-ask) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by reinstalling the ROM from scratch.

After a full wipe, and a complete fresh re-install, it started to work perfectly (still on android 7.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with my S7, and I solved it by:

- Booting into TWRP
- Factory Reset
- Flash [Lineage](https://download.lineageos.org/)
- Flash [OpenGapps](http://opengapps.org/)
- Flash [SuperSU SR5](https://download.chainfire.eu/1014/SuperSU/SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip?retrieve_file)
- Reboot
- Install TitaniumBackup
- Restore Apps

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Cyanogenmod 14.1 Nightly (the last available one from 25/12/2016) on an OnePlus One, and I've tried all the things you've done. But after deleting some unused apps I was able to start Titanium Backup. I'm sorry I can't explain this, but maybe you'll be able to run Titanium Backup by deleting some Apps.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I managed to starting it by reinstalling the mod. I had the impression something went wrong with the flash and actually it started after a full wipe and re-flash.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by manually moving the back up files (needed only) to another folder (will be set as back up location in the preference).. i guess some back up file cause the issue